# Conditional Maximum of two independent exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We have $X \sim Exp(\alpha)$ and $Y \sim Exp(\beta)$. We also have $Z = \max(X,Y)$. We want to find the probability that **$P(Z > z \mid X > \tau, Y > \tau)$** and **$P(Z \leq z \mid Z > \tau)$**.

---

I started as:

$P(Z \leq z) = \max(X,Y)$
$= P(X \leq z ) P(Y \leq z )$

Then, $f_{Z \mid Z>\tau} = \frac{f_Z(z)}{P(Z > \tau)}$
and $P(Z \leq z \mid Z > \tau) = \frac{d}{dz} f_{Z \mid Z > \tau}(z)$

Am I doing it right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use any conditional densities. For $z >\tau$ We have $P(Z \leq z, X>\tau, Y>\tau)=P(\tau <X \leq z, \tau <Y \leq z)=P\tau <X \leq z) P(\tau <X \leq z)=(\int_{\tau}^{z} \alpha e^{-\alpha x} dx)(\int_{\tau}^{z} \beta e^{-\beta x} dx)$. Now $P(Z>\tau |X>\tau,Y>\tau)=1-(Z\leq \tau |X>\tau,Y>\tau)=1-\frac {(\int_{\tau}^{z} \alpha e^{-\alpha x} dx)(\int_{\tau}^{z} \beta e^{-\beta x} dx)} {P(X>\tau)P(Y>\tau)}$. Can you proceed?

Comment: In the denominator, should not it be: $P(X> \tau)$?

Comment: @jhon_wick Thank you. That was  a typo.

Comment: One thought, what difference will there be: if i want to compute: $P(Z \leq z \mid Z > \tau)$?

Comment: This is quite different. $Z >\tau$ is same as $(X>\tau) \cup (Y>\tau)$ instead of  $(X>\tau) \cap (Y>\tau)$.

Comment: Could you please add to the answer, how should I proceed to derive $P(Z \leq z \mid Z > \tau)$? Thanks so much.